# What is the timing of Yoshimitsu's K attack from Super Dragonfly?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

While in the Super Dragonfly stance (spinning his sword like a helicopter far overhead), Yoshimitsu has an attack that is listed in the movelist as KK. All this does is the same thing as the normal K attack, except that he doesn't damage himself at the end and stays on his feet. This is *much* more useful than the standard version.

The problem is, I have no clue how to execute it. If I mash K as fast as I can, he always falls. The 2 or 3 times (out of 100 attempts in training mode) I've actually gotten this command to execute properly, I couldn't emulate it immediately afterwards.

What is the timing for the second press of K? There is also a just version of this attack as well, but I would be fine just being able to consistently execute the normal version without damaging myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper time to hit the second `K` is slightly before his feet are about to hit the ground (but definitely before his feet hit the ground).

Doing this was particularly difficult if I was trying to perform it off to the side of an enemy - I actually found it much more reliable to practice this as part of a combo. I suspect this is due to the zoomed-out camera shake when you have distance and are moving quickly vertically.

I'd recommend getting close to an enemy, using his `1B` launcher, his `8A` into Super Dragonfly, then immediately hit `K` for the kick. You'll come down and hit your opponent; try and time it so that you hit the second `K` right as you make contact with your opponent. This will allow you to get a feel for exactly when it should be hit.